# How can I prevent Safari from upscaling images

Tags: css, image, scaling

Safari is upscaling an image 150% on 2560x1440 screen.

My image displays fine in Chrome on smaller screens but gets upscaled in Safari. http://patrycjajadach.com/about/

I added following code to page.php and single.php:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

I would like browsers to load original size image on larger screens.
Is there an easy fix which a WordPress amateur would be able to apply?
[normal image size in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvVTX.jpg)

[upscaled image in Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwOzm.jpg)

Comment: Can you produce a [mcve]? I see you're currently working on the site - its source is changing before my very eyes. So if people are willing to take a look, they're all looking at different versions of the site.

Comment: I looked at your site and it renders the same in Chrome and Safari for me, no scaling whatsoever

Comment: @MrLister I don't know which part of the surce is responsible for this issue. From what I read, it could be Safari related and the code I tried (see ablove) is said to solve the problem. I could have missed something though as it did not help in my case. I'm done trying various fixes now so if you're still willing to look at it...

Comment: @RubenHelsloot Thanks for checking. What resolution was the screen?

Comment: @elHuzar 1680x1050 on Macbook Pro 15'

Comment: @RubenHelsloot many thanks!